# Laravel multiple models in controller

Tags: laravel, model, controller, share

This question regards the structure of applications when using laravel.

I have a view for making a sale/purchase from a company. This single view contains a client search, product list, service list and a staff list. Each of the items listed above has their own model. In the view, i would say search for a client which will call a function within the controller and populate a list. Same for the products and services etc etc.

What confuses me is that for the client search i would click a button that would fire to a url like /clients/search/search string, which would return the array of clients to display on the page. This function seems as if it would be appropriate within the client controller. I am unsure as to how i would be able to maintain the information from the client search and other parts of the sale to then submit it all together under one single controller (let's call it InvoiceController).

Can controllers share the functions from other controller? Do i simply store the information in a session variable? Do i simply put all relative functions to this sale under the InvoiceController?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation, it appeared that AJAX was the simplest answer. In this case i used Angular JS and had that running a controller to fetch each segment of the Invoice, then use the main InvoiceController in Laravel to fire the final update.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a search for clients against the client controller, then when you select the client add this (client_id) to your invoice form. then save this with other invoice info via the invoice controller